# RoR- A method processed as HTML as well as PNG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have given this in my route.

```
get '/custom_page/:page_name' => 'custom_page#load_content'
```

And when i click a menu with url say '/custom_page/abc' it works fine.. It goes to the controller and also the view with name load_content. But the Issue is the app crashes in terminal. Its not shown in front end though..
I get these error messages in my terminal.. Any guess..?

```
Started GET "/en/custom_page/abc" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-16 11:26:25 +0530
Processing by CustomPageController#load_content as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "page_name"=>"abc"}
  MenuItem Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `menu_items`.* FROM `menu_items` WHERE `menu_items`.`url` = '/custom_page/abc' ORDER BY `menu_items`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CustomPage Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `custom_pages`.* FROM `custom_pages` WHERE `custom_pages`.`id` = 51 ORDER BY `custom_pages`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered custom_page/load_content.html.erb within layouts/calculator (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_calculator_script_top.html.erb (36.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_calculator_header.html.erb (80.5ms)
  MenuItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `menu_items`.* FROM `menu_items` ORDER BY `menu_items`.`menu_priority` ASC
  Rendered layouts/_calculator_menu.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_calculator_script_bottom.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 168ms (Views: 139.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)


Started GET "/en/custom_page/favicon.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-16 11:26:26 +0530
Processing by CustomPageController#load_content as PNG
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "page_name"=>"favicon"}
  MenuItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `menu_items`.* FROM `menu_items` WHERE `menu_items`.`url` = '/custom_page/favicon' ORDER BY `menu_items`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_request.text.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_session.text.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_environment.text.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_backtrace.text.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_title.text.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /home/nithin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/exception_notification-4.0.1/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.text.erb (31.3ms)
```

Seems like it renders the correct page first (Processing by CustomPageController#load_content as HTML) and then it is processing as PNG.
(Processing by CustomPageController#load_content as PNG)
My Controller

```
class CustomPageController < ActionController::Base
  layout 'calculator'

  def load_content    
    page_name = (params[:page_name]).split("_").join(" ")
    session[:tab] = page_name
    @menu_item = MenuItem.where(url: "/custom_page/"+params[:page_name])
    if @menu_item.first.custom_page.present?
      @description = @menu_item.first.custom_page.description
    else
      @description = "CUSTOM PAGE NOT FOUND..."
    end         
  end

end
```

Comment: can you post your controller code

Comment: perhaps there are no menu_items? try change condition to `if @menu_item.any? and @menu_item.first.custom_page.present?`